# PHP, JS - Documenting and saving DATE/TIME to re-appear after browser closed

Tags: javascript, php, time, onclick

I currently have a sitation where I can click on an image and it will return a new image, and in the previous grid-item, it will return the day and time I clicked it.

What I want is to have this BUT where I also can see the updated image and clicked time after closing and re-opening the browser. - What is the easiest / quickest way to achieve this?

I feel like adding to my database would be a way forward, but if that is what I would need to do, how would I go about storing and out-putting the time based on the time I click?

(This is not intended to be a live site, or for others to see or use, so local quick-fixes are viable).

```
foreach ($flavours as $key => $flavour) {
    echo "<div class='grid-container'>";
        echo "<div class='item7'><p id='p3'>Sylus: </p></div>";
        echo "<div class='item8'><img src='htts://i.i.com/k.jpg' onclick='cS(this)'  /></div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

```
function cS(element) {

    if (element.src == "htts://i.i.com/k.jpg") 
    {
        element.src = "http://i.i.com/v.jpg";
        var d = moment().format('dddd HH:mm');
        element.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstChild.innerHTML = "Sylus: " + d;
    }
    else 
    {
        element.src = "htts://i.i.com/k.jpg";
        element.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstChild.innerHTML = "Sylus: ";
    }
}
```

Comment: The local storage in your other comment is not quite used that way. I could put an example together, but know that references such as `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, etc. could get problematic if the element order changes for whatever reason between browser reloads. Which means that the element order would need to be static in nature without having some other specific handling to avoid this rigid expectation. I'm pondering if there could be a better way to handle. You have already mentioned storing to the DB instead, which can avoid the localStorage situation mentioned above, by loading from SQL data.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. The static should not be a problem, as I do not have intention of really calling other arguments than the one made - the checklist will always be the same, it is just a matter of noting the time they are checked daily. However, I do see that you are implying that I would be structurally better off using a DB. This ought not be a problem, but I am not sure how to record-output the time then - would this be through an SQL query? (I will go ahead and look into this tonight to see if I can progress further myself too with this idea in mind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example using `localStorage`. This will find the `<p>` tag elements within the body, and then uses each element to get the id for reference.

I tried using a fiddle here, but the site has a security complaint with the localStorage.

Copy/paste this code to a file to give it a try. Note that you will likely need to update the `moment.js` reference in this code to match your file path.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>localStorage example</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="moment.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='grid-container'>
            <div class='item7'><p id='p0'>Sylus: </p></div>
            <div class='item8'><img src='htts://i.i.com/k.jpg' onclick='cS(this)'  /></div>
        </div>
        <div class='grid-container'>
            <div class='item7'><p id='p1'>Sylus: </p></div>
            <div class='item8'><img src='htts://i.i.com/k.jpg' onclick='cS(this)'  /></div>
        </div>
        <script>
        function cS(element) {
            var pTag = element.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstChild;

            if (element.src == "htts://i.i.com/k.jpg") 
            {
                element.src = "http://i.i.com/v.jpg";
                var d = moment().format('dddd HH:mm');
                var pText = 'Sylus: ' + d;

                pTag.innertHTML = pText;

                // Set (save) a reference to browser localStorage
                localStorage.setItem(pTag.id, pText);
            }
            else 
            {
                element.src = "htts://i.i.com/k.jpg";
                pTag.innerHTML = "Sylus: ";

                // Remove the stored reference. (delete this if not needed)
                localStorage.removeItem(pTag.id);
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            pElements = $('body').find('p').each(function(index, element) {
                // Get the localStorage items. The retrieved <p> elements,
                // we use their id value to reference the key in storage.
                storageItem = localStorage.getItem(element.id);

                if (storageItem) {
                   $('#' + element.id).text(storageItem);
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

After clicking an image (will need to replace with something real), open the browser's web inspector interface, click the `Storage` tab, and then expand the Local Storage in the list (see image below), and choose the file being tested.

There will be key/value pairs displayed. The keys are references to the `<p>` tag id's, and the value will have a label-date strings such as `Sylus: Wednesday 22:28`.

Once you see an entry, or two, being set to the storage, close and then reopen the browser tab. The `<p>` elements that had dates should be reloaded with their values from the storage.

The browser's Local Storage area should be similar to the image below:

[image]

Comment: Ahh, so this is how the localStorage should work, thanks for showing me the way here. I have managed to replicate this and it works

Comment: ... But unfortunately it is not quite working as hoped since I have multiple 'flavours' being output, a new 'Sylus' would be shown for each 'flavour' and therefor need its own timestamp. While I am able to output a timestamp for each currently with this, upon re-loading the window it only takes the last input-time and outputs that, so the whole list of 'flavours' do not get saved/re-displayed. And I think I see that it is because each time I click a Sylus it saves to a p1, but upon reload, it doesn't know how to seperate all the different p1's.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you again, every time you post I am able to learn new things from you. I appreciate and enjoy that a lot.

Comment: Thanks! It should save to it's own reference, and have it's own timestamp, if the IDs are unique, or there could be something else. I'd probably have to see more of what you've tried to do.

Comment: I can see that it does indeed create it's own timestamp in the example you handed, but when I tried to incorporate it into my foreach loop, it does not. I think perhaps then I may be calling my foreach loop in an inneficient way. I will tamper more with this. May I send you my full code and DB somewhere to easier 'bare all'? (Sorry if the question is innaproptiate).

Comment: With your loop, try using a variable such `$i` to create unique `<p>` tag id's that looks similar to `<p id='p$i'> ...` to get the p0, p1, p2, etc. `id` values. Initialize the variable to `$i = 0;` before the loop, use the variable at the element id as shown here and then bump the variable value just before the end of the foreach.  Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Fantastic! With this I put `$i = 0;` before my `foreach` loop, `$i ++;` at the end of the loop. In my loop I used `<p id='s$i'>Sylus: </p>`, `<p id='a$i'>Atreyu: </p>` etc for my entries and have `pElements = $('body').find('p') ...` for each of those and this works perfectly. In now each `id` within each `flavour` are stored and output entirely unique. Thank you so much for mentoring me in this project, Paul.

Answer (score 0):

save it to local storage, or a cookie with the exp. date too far in the future

Comment: I am sorry, I have spent the last day or so trying to work with this answer. It seems like a sensible choice, however all the information I am getting when researching on it is based on using arrays and pre-defined items. The thing that I want to be 'stored' and output, primarily, is the day/time which is determined by the time of a click. The nearest thing I got to was trying like this, but still to no avail; 
`var localstorage.d = moment().format('dddd HH:mm');
 element.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstChild.innerHTML = "Sylus: " + localstorage.d;`